# Multivariable function which is both convex and concave

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a multivariable function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ which is both convex and concave, a new function is constructed: $h(x) = f(x)-f(0)$.

I need to prove the following twi things:

1. $g(tx)=t \cdot g(x), \forall t \ge0$
2. $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y), \forall x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

In addition, based on those two thing I need to prove that $f$ is linear ($f(x)=a^Tx+b$).

I know that for any $\lambda\in[0, 1]$, $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$, and thus I know to prove the first thing for $t\in[0, 1]$, but I don't know what to do when $t>1$ and how to prove the second thing.

Comment: If $x \neq 0,$ then $\hat x = x / \|x\|$ has norm 1, does this help?

Comment: @WilliamM. I don't understand how it helps

Answer (score 1):

For (1) when $t > 1$, you can rewrite it as $g(sy) = s \cdot g(y)$ where $s = 1/t \in [0, 1]$ and $y = tx$. Then it reduces to the "$t \in [0,1]$" case that you already proved.

---

For (2),
\begin{align}
g(x+y)
= g\left(\frac{1}{2} (2x) + \frac{1}{2} (2y)\right)
= \frac{1}{2} g(2x) + \frac{1}{2} g(2y).
\end{align}
Then use (1).

Comment: I can't understand how it helps me, since $sy=x$, and not $tx$

Comment: @Dani $g(sy) = s \cdot g(y)$ becomes $g(t) = (1/t) \cdot g(tx)$.